# Finding a tab name using string

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that I don't know the exact code to find a tab using a variable.

For now my macro create a new tab in another workbook using the Range D26 as the name of my active workbook and is able to copy my form in the other workbooks but not in the right sheets. In fact it just send me to the debug.

```
Dim Titre As String

Titre = Range("D26").Value

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\charl\Desktop\Programe comptable projet\Menu automatisé Test\Feuille de projet.xlsx"

Workbooks("Feuille de projet.xlsx").Worksheets(Titre).Range("B2") = Workbooks("Menu Automatisé.xlsm").Sheets("Fiche de création de projet").Range("D8").Value
```

I expect the program to copy of my form in the other workbooks in the tab I just created using the button. (The tab is created first)

Comment: Are you sure the sheet `Titre` is created in the destination workbook, before you actually call it to set the `Range("B2")`? What is the error you receive and on which line? In the code you show, you're not creating any sheet in the destination workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just found why it's not working. I was not precise enough for my string variable.

```
Dim Titre As String
```

Titre = Workbooks("Menu Automatisé.xlsm").Sheets("Fiche de création de projet").Range("D26").Value